# Add progressbar to DataTemplate of ListBox ItemTemplate in WPF but does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to set a progressbar onClick in my UserControl to IsIndeterminate="True" if I click on the button StartScan.

I have the following xaml in my usercontrol:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="myList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Button x:Name="StartScan" Grid.Column="1" Click="Start_Click" Margin="20,0,0,0">Start</Button>
                    <ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Grid.Column="2" Height="22" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="True" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

but all I get is `psbStatus does not exist in the current context`, thats now gone after I added: `ProgressBar pbStatus = new ProgressBar();` to my userControl.

But Im still unable to access the properties like IsIndeterminate or Visibility. For example to show or hide the progressbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in DataTemplate so it doesn't exist in code behind as normal controls do. What you can do is alter this template a bit and do everything in XAML. This is my attempt:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="myList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <ToggleButton x:Name="StartScan" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="Start" IsChecked="False"/>
                <ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Grid.Column="2" Height="22" Width="50" Minimum="0" Maximum="100">
                    <ProgressBar.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                            <Setter Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="False"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=StartScan}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ProgressBar.Style>
                </ProgressBar>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What I'm doing here is adding a style to a progress bar. This style defines a DataTrigger that is binded to the ToggleButton.IsChecked. As You can see I have changed from Button to ToggleButton since ToggleButton provides a property IsChecked. Whenever I check the button I will set the IsIndeterminate to True.

**EDIT** - without using xaml and doing it in code behind.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="myList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button x:Name="StartScan" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="Start" Click="StartScan_Click"/>
                <ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Grid.Column="2" Height="22" Width="50" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

We remove all the triggers and keep the XAML definition as you did. In the event method we have to obtain the templated parent. This is the content presenter in our case since the item is shown in ListBox. After that we have to obtain the template and finally obtain the progress bar instance from within the template. After that it is ieasy as it involves the usual logic.

```
private void StartScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This is the button
    var btn = sender as Button;

    // Now we get the template that the button is in.
    var contentPresenter = (btn.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter);

    // Finally we find the progress by its name in the template. Also we have to pass the content
    // presenter as the second argument since this is where the actual instance of the control is.
    var progress = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("pbStatus", contentPresenter) as ProgressBar;

    // Do your logic normally as you would.
    progress.IsIndeterminate = !progress.IsIndeterminate;
    btn.Content = progress.IsIndeterminate ? "Stop" : "Start";
}
```

Comment: Solution with Codebehind is my favorite, thank you for your time.